# C++ Switch Statement Skips to the default option after first try

Tags: c++

I am working on a menu using switch case. I've tried running the program and the menu seems to work, but I don't know when I tried going back to the menu, it won't read the other cases. In the first try it works, but after that it won't go to other cases then it skips to the default value.

Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
int path = 0;
std::string search, line, productName, iprice, quantity, productType, again = "y";
using namespace std;
std::ifstream ReferenceList;
std::ofstream Sales;
void menu();
void priceSearch();
void recordSales();
void addItem();
int main() {
    char option = 'y';
    do {
        system("CLS");
        menu();
        system("CLS");
        switch (path) {
        case 1:
            priceSearch();
            break;
        case 2:
            recordSales();
            break;
        case 3:
            addItem();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please Only Enter: {1 2 3}";
            break;
        }
        cout << "\nGo back to Main Menu? Press Y to Continue: ";
        cin >> option;
    } while (option == 'y' || option == 'Y');
}
```

This is the code for the void menu ()

```
void menu() {
    std::cout << "TINDAHAN ALL IN ONE PURPOSE PROGRAM\n";
    std::cout << "Functions:\n";
    std::cout << "Press 1 to Find Price List\n";
    std::cout << "Press 2 to Record Sales\n";
    std::cout << "Press 3 to Add New Product\n";
    std::cin >> path;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted never alters the value of `path`. I assume `menu` does this, so you need to post the code for that function or whatever function updates `path`.

Comment: Edit : added the code for the menu function

Comment: Unrelated, rather than a global for `path`, consider returning the chosen value from `menu` and stuffing it into a local variable.

Comment: `cin` is probably failing, you should check and clear the steam state

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Because I had to bash your code into a runnable example I may have accidentally fixed the bug or missed a bug inside one of the functions I stubbed out. This is one of the dangers of not posting a [mcve]. I recommend making a MRE. Often making the MRE reduces the noise to the point that you can see and fix the bug yourself without needing to ask the question.

Comment: So if you enter something into thr console, doesn't the enter/new line also get put into the stream